# How can I include custom Gutenberg Blocks in a theme?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor, include

I know that officially Wordpress wants people to include blocks as companion plugins, and I understand their reasoning for that.

I am building a theme with a very specific usecase though and I would like to include my custom blocks in the theme for the easiest possible user installation experience.

How can I do this?

Comment: Blocks can be include in the same way they would in a plugin, but instead in the `functions.php` file. In the end its just calling the corresponding hook.

Comment: @Alvaro You would think that, but for some reason that's not working for me :(

Comment: David, if you could share the attempts you have tried maybe we can help you with them.